# how to align labeltext to top left in textfield while having maxline is more than 1 flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, textfield

In this app i want to show label text of textfield in top left position but I get label text in center in vertical.

I try other solution to put expand and null maxline but did not work.

here is my code of textfield

```
TextField(
      controller: textEditingController,
      obscureText: passwordVisible,
      keyboardType: inputType,
      readOnly: readOnly,
      maxLines: maxLine,
      focusNode: focusNode,
      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
            borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF434fd9), width: 0),
          ),
          enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
            borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF434fd9), width: 0),
          ),
          disabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
            borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF434fd9), width: 0.0),
          ),
          focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
            borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF434fd9), width: 0.0),
          ),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 15),
          hintText: hintText,
          labelText: labelText,
          suffixIcon: prefixIcon.isNotEmpty
              ?  IconButton(
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(prefixIcon))
              : null,
          suffixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: 10.0, minWidth: 10.0,),
          suffixStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
    );
```

here is my output

[image]

I want title and description on top left but I get center left please give some suggestion on this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `alignLabelWithHint: true` in `InputDecoration`